# Default with SDL_RendererFlip Horizontal (SDL, C ++)

Tags: c++, sprites, sdl2

When I execute my sprite sheet animation and apply renderer_flip_horizontal, a line appears in the sprite.

Without the flip render, everything works fine.

**Example image:**

[image: Sprites Flip None and Horizontal]

**Note:** The sprites are correctly aligned. The flip is by sprite (not to the full sheet). 
I also use SDL_Renderer SetLogicalSize(256, 224), and the size of the window is 800 x 600.

Could you explain why this happens?

Thanks in advance.